# How to have a circle follow path in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want the user to be able to click three spots on the canvas to form two line segments with three circles for each place the user clicked. When the user clicks a button, a red circle shows up at the first circle the user clicked, then follows the path the user drew. As it reaches the 2nd circle and finally the last circle, some form of alert pops up once it reaches those points.

Comment: Please show some code of what you have attempted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not going to make all of this for you. However, here is a starting point

1) Make sure you can capture mouse events in the canvas. This question will get you started [Html5 canvas and jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811791/html5-canvas-and-jquery)

2) Understand the problem you are coding. You need a data structure like so:

```
points{
    a : {x : None, y : None},
    b : {x : None, y : None},
    c : {x : None, y : None}  
};
```

3) Everytime the user clicks, update `a`, then `b`, then `c`. When you get to `c`, use trigonometry to animate the line being drawn. This can be done with `setTimeout` or `setInterval`